# TypeError this.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm new in react and I get this problem here is my constructor :

```
 constructor(props){
 super(props)
 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
 this.state={
  user: {},
  email: "",
  password: ""
 }}
```

And when I call my method `handleChange` from input:

```
<Input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" 
        onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

...

```
handleChange(e){
this.setState({
  [e.target.name] : e.target.value
})}
```

I get the error:

> this.setstate is not a function

Can someone help me to solve the problem please?

The full component code

```
 import React from "react";
 import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
 import { Image, Button, Text, Input, Icon } from "react-native-elements";

 import * as firebase from 'firebase'
 import config from '../config'

 class SignIn extends React.Component {

   constructor(props){
     super(props)
     this.login = this.login.bind(this)
     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
     this.authListener = this.authListener.bind(this)
     this.state={
       user: {},
       email: "",
       password: ""
     }
     this.setState={
       users: {}
     }
     if (!firebase.apps.length) {
       firebase.initializeApp(config)
     }
   }

   authListener(){
     firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
       if(user){
         this.setState({user})
       }
       else{
         this.setState({user:null})
       }
     })
   }

   componentDidMount(){
     this.authListener()
   }

   login(e){
     console.log("Se connecter")
     e.preventDefault();
     firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email,                     
     this.state.password).then((u)=>{console.log(u)}).catch((err)=>                
    {console.log(err)})
  }

   handleChange(e){
     this.setState({
       [e.target.name] : e.target.value
     })
     console.log("Se Handlechange ")
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
         <View style={styles.container}>
           <Image
             source={require("../Images/khouddwak.png")}
             style={{ height: 200 }}
           />
           <Text style={styles.titletxt}>Se Connecter</Text>
         </View>
         <View style={{ alignSelf: "center", marginTop: 50 }}>
           <View style={styles.viewtxt}>
             <Icon type="font-awesome" name="envelope" size={25} />
             <Input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" 
             onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} />
           </View>
           <View style={styles.viewtxt}>
             <Icon type="font-awesome" name="lock" size={30} />
             <Input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" 
             onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} />
           </View>
           <Button title="Se Connecter" type="outline" style={styles.buttons} 
           onPress={()=>this.login()} />
         </View>
         <View style={{ position: "absolute", left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }}>
           <Image
             source={require("../Images/footerimage.png")}
             style={{ height: 50 }}
           />
         </View>
       </View>
     );
   }
 }

 export default SignIn;
```

Comment: The shared code snippet looks okay to me, can you please share the full component? I'm thinking if you defined accidentally a function component instead of a class component. Thanks!

Comment: did you try onChange= {() => this.handleChange}

Comment: Yes, this should be ok - I thought it was a `this` binding issue but then saw you have `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)` in the constructor, which should solve this problem. Can you share the full component (or if it's long, the minimum necessary to observe the problem)?

Comment: @MayankMehtani I think you meant `onChange= {(e) => this.handleChange(e)}`, but this shouldn't be necessary when they're `bind`ing the method in the constructor - the arrow function is just an alternative solution to the same problem

Comment: The same error i will update the question to add the full component code now and thanks for you guys for trying to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is here:

```js
this.setState={
 users: {}
}
```

inside the constructor you are redefining the `setState` method, thats why is not a function, you are assigning an object to it.

Answer (score 0):

use arrow function in this

```
handleChange=(e)=>{
this.setState({
  [e.target.name] : e.target.value
})}
```

don't use bind line , remove `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)`

```
<Input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" 
       onChange={()=>this.handleChange} />
```

I hope, it's useful for you.